# Is there a way to change the order of items when wrapping?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a part of a website, with 3 parts (let's call them A, B, C), where A and B are beside each other (aligned to touch opposite sides of a container), and below them is C, but when A, and B don't fit beside each other in the container, B wraps below C instead of between A and C.

A, B and C all have expanding-collapsing components, and the container can be resized by other elements, so all their sizes are unknown. This means that **using @media is out of the question.**

Expected result: 
When A and B fit beside each other:
[image: When A and B fit beside each other]
When they don't:
[image: When they don't]

Is this possible to achieve with flexbox or grid?

This is as far as I got:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>flexbox black magic</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:50%; border:4px solid blue; margin:8px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap;">
        <div style="width: 100px; height: 60px; border: 4px solid red; margin:8px;">a</div>
        <div style="width: 70px; height: 30px; border: 4px solid green; margin:8px;">b</div>
        <div style="width: 100%">
            <div style="width: 100%; max-width: 240px; height: 100px; border: 4px solid orange; margin:8px;">c</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But this not only wraps the elements in the wrong order, it also makes C stick out of the container.

Comment: yes, order and mediaquerie   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I think the third `div` in which there is the `div` with `c` shouldn't be there, [check this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v96r8qx2/). About the order in which it should be wrapped, I think the key is in `order` and the media queries. I recommend you to read [this Flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. All elements have expanding parts, so their sizes are all unknown. I need a solution that works dinamically.

Comment: i think this guide will help you https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea using float, yes float. Resize the blue container and see the result:

```css
.box {
  width: 50%;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  margin: 8px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size:0; /* this will make sure the pseudo element won't have any size */
  overflow: auto;
  resize: horizontal;
}
.box > * {
  font-size:initial; /* we reset the font for child element */
  margin:8px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
/* the below is used with text-align:justify to have the correct alignment on wrap */
.box::before {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
}
.box::after {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
/**/
.a {
  max-width: 100px;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  height: 60px;
  float:left; /* we float a */
}

.b {
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.c {
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  max-width: 240px;
  float:left; /* and we float c */
  clear:left; /* don't forget this to make "c" always below "a" */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="a" style="border: 4px solid red;">a</div>
  <div class="c" style="border: 4px solid orange;">c</div>
  <div class="b" style="border: 4px solid green;">b</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work exactly how I expected it to. I'm still trying to understand exactly how it works, but once I do, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @vitrack let me know if you have any question. The main trick is the use of float and how text wrap around. To better understand replace "b" with a lot of text to see how it behaves: https://jsfiddle.net/5m6s9noe/

Comment: I accepted your answer, but I still have one question. Why is it, that when I use font-size:0 on .box and font-size: initial on .box>*, it works fine, but if instead I put font-size:0 on .box::after,.box::before, than there is a certain size of .box where .b jumps below .box:after ?

Comment: @vitrack because the before/after are empty spaces that have 0 width but will take some vertical space since they are texts. You need to reset the font-size of their container so they don't take any space (to make their line box 0). Applying font-size to them won't work because their parent still have a font size and the existance of a space (even with a font-size:0) will trigger the creation of a line of text ... When you apply it to container you will target both the parent and the child element (due to inheritance)

Comment: @vitrack to better illustrate check this: https://jsfiddle.net/5m6s9noe/1/ .. only when applying font-size:0 to parent (and the child inherit it) we will have 0 height otherwise we still have a height even if the child is having a font-size:0

Answer (score 2):

One way (using mobile-first approach) would be set the `.c` as your second element in the HTML

Then inside the media query you would set `display:flex` to parent and the `order: 1` to `.c`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0
}

.wrap {
  width: 50%;
  border: 4px solid blue;
}

.wrap>div {
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 8px;
}

.a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  border-color: red
}

.b {
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  border-color: green
}

.c {
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  height: 100px;
  border-color: orange;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .c {
    order: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using @media is out of the question for me, because the container is being resized by a navigation drawer opening and closing. I added clarification to my question.

Comment: well you can't change the natural order of elements (using CSS only) without media queries

Answer (score 2):

One good rule of thumb is to always start from the mobile layout. Use **grid-template-areas** and make sure that the sizes of the surrounding areas are well defined, using **grid-template-columns** and **grid-template-rows**. Always use `fr` values when specifying the columns and rows.

Please consider reading [MDN Docs on CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) and [MDN Docs on Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for responsive design. CSS Grid will make your life easier but it takes time learning.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .container {
            width: auto;
            height: 300px;
            border: 4px solid blue; 
            margin: 8px;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
            grid-template-areas: 
            "a"
            "c"
            "b";
        }
        .red-box {
            grid-area: a;
            width: 100px;
            height: 60px;
            border: 4px solid red;
            margin: 8px;
        }     
        .green-box {
            grid-area: b;
            width: 70px;
            height: 30px;
            border: 4px solid green;
            margin: 8px;
            
        }   
        .orange-box {
            grid-area: c;
            width: 100%; 
            max-width: 240px; 
            height: 100px; 
            border: 4px solid orange; 
            margin: 8px;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
            .container {
                grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
                grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
                grid-template-areas: 
                "a . b"
                "c c .";
                margin: 0;
                padding: 8px;
                grid-gap: 21px;
            }
            .red-box {
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
            .green-box {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
            .orange-box {
                padding-top: 21px;
                max-width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="red-box">a</div> <!-- red ends -->
            <div class="green-box">b</div> <!-- green ends -->
            <div class="orange-box">c</div> <!-- orange ends -->
        </div> <!-- container ends -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I needed. I added some clarification to my question.